# How to convert milliseconds to a readable date with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a milliseconds integer, and I am trying to convert it to a readable date in the format of `yyyy MM dd` (2014-08-06).

```
var maxDate = 1407267771429;
maxDate = new Date(maxDate);
maxDateFinal = maxDate.toString('yyyy MM dd');
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sk49c0jz/)**

Although, `maxDateFinal` always seems to equal `Wed Aug 06 2014 05:42:51 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)`

I have added `console.log()` after each call in my fiddle to demonstrate the change of the variables, although it seems as if `toString()` is doing absolutely nothing to the date at all.

Comment: what is the source of your `var maxDate`? Minitech's answer seems correct.

Comment: toString simply just prints out the date, It does not format it.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format javascript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn’t have built-in date formatting. You can do it yourself, but there are also a few libraries out there.

```
function pad(s, width, character) {
    return new Array(width - s.toString().length + 1).join(character) + s;
}

var maxDate = new Date(1407267771429);
var maxDateFormatted =
    maxDate.getFullYear() +
    ' ' + pad(maxDate.getMonth() + 1, 2, '0') +
    ' ' + pad(maxDate.getDate(), 2, '0');
```

Comment: Ahh alright, interesting. Does jQuery have built in date formatting? The solution you posted works very well, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately JavaScript's `Date` does not provide arbitrary formatting with the `toString()` method (or any other method). To get your date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, you could use the `toISOString()` and then the `substr(start, length)` method. For instance:

```
var maxDate = new Date(1407267771429);
var isoDate = maxDate.toISOString(); // 2014-08-05T19:42:51.429Z
isoDate.substr(0, 10); // 2014-08-05
```

This should work in all major browsers including IE9+. To support support IE8 and older browsers, you could do something like this:

```
function toISODate(milliseconds) {
    var date = new Date(milliseconds);
    var y = date.getFullYear()
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = date.getDate();
    m = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
    d = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
    return [y, m, d].join('-');
}
```

Alternatively you could look into something like Moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) or jquery-dateFormat (https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat).